# Devise authenticating with additional field company_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to authenticate user with `company_id` beside `email`, `password` (Devise's default).

I just searched Devise wiki [sign-in-using-their-username-or-email](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), and [Scope-login-to-subdomain](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain)

I just find out about Devise, and I am not good to understand clearly. So, someone guide me how to add new field for authenticating. How to change the Devise in initializers, User model, etc

One more thing: could you explain the difference between `config.authentication_keys` and `config.request_keys` in initializers\devise.erb. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by just adding this in the initilizers/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email , :company_id ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, need like two models:

do in your models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, authentication_keys: [:email]
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, authentication_keys: [:email, :company_id]
end
```

[How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)